# connection cannot be made with derby client jdbc driver

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, derby

im using Eclipse Helios Java EE IDE for Web Developers,Version: 1.3.0. connection with derby embeded jdbc driver is workin fine but i cannot make connection with derby client jdbc driver... what should i do to make it work,please help me...

Comment: And the exception stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

> connection with derby embeded jdbc driver is workin fine but i cannot make connection with derby client jdbc driver

Providing details (what you did, what didn't work, etc) is generally useful to get good answers. Here are some things to check though:

- make sure `derbyclient.jar` is on the classpath
- make sure you are using `org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver` as driver class
- make sure the URL follows the following format `jdbc:derby://<host>:<port>/<database>`
- make sure the network server has been **started**(!)